pandas dataframe group columns extract first row of values
In this dataframe I want to create a column 'desired_output' that takes the first value of 'lumpsum' from the 'index' of each 'ID'.
data = [
    [1, 12334, 1, 12334],
    [1, 12334, 1, 12334],
    [1, 12334, 1, 12334],
    [1, 12334, 1, 12334],
    [1, 34567, 1, 12334],
    [1, 34567, 1, 12334],
    [2, 45788, 1, 45788],
    [2, 45788, 2, 45788],
    [2, 23467, 2, 45788],
    [2, 5678, 3, 5678],
    [2, 4567, 3, 5678],
    [3, 56832, 1, 56832],
    [3, 43456, 1, 56832],
    [3, 2378, 2, 2378],
    [4, 6754, 1, 6754],
    [4, 3456, 2, 3456]
]

columns = ['ID', 'lumpsum', 'index', 'desired_output']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
print(df)

I used this code tried to create the 'desired_output' column, and called this new column 'test'.
df['test']=df.groupby('ID', 'index')['lumpsum'].transform('first')

The output completely ignored my grouping using 'index' and only returned the first 'lumpsum' value of each 'ID'. how should I rectify this?

pass multiple columns as a list to groupby function df['test']=df.groupby(['ID', 'index'])['lumpsum'].transform('first')

df.groupby(["index"]).transform(lambda x: x.head(1)).ffill().astype(int)

    ID  lumpsum  index  desired_output
0    1    12334      1           12334
1    1    12334      1           12334
2    1    12334      1           12334
3    1    12334      1           12334
4    1    34567      1           12334
5    1    34567      1           12334
6    2    45788      1           45788
7    2    45788      2           45788
8    2    23467      2           45788
9    2     5678      3            5678
10   2     4567      3            5678
11   3    56832      1           56832
12   3    43456      1           56832
13   3     2378      2            2378
14   4     6754      1            6754
15   4     3456      2            3456

